# Does automatic semi-colon insertion in JS affect for loops with the first { on a new line?

Tags: javascript, semantics, automatic-semicolon-insertion

Will JS auto semi-colon insertion place a semi-colon at the end of `for(...)` like I've placed in the following example or is it safe to break the bracket onto a new line with for loops?

```
for(...);
{
   ...
}
```

I've found plenty of info saying what is affected, but nothing specific to my question, which leads me to believe it may not be affected, but I would like to find a concrete answer.

*Personally, I prefer not to break onto a new line with brackets like this but the question has been raised ;)*

Comment: Why not just try it out?

Comment: Couldn't you just test this and see?

Comment: I've never run into a situation where I couldn't break curly braces onto the next line. (maybe someone could fill me into where you cannot?)

Comment: @pattmorter When returning an object literal, you get unexpected results. `return { foo: 'bar' };` returns an object, whereas `return<newline>{foo:'bar'}` returns undefined because of ASI.

Comment: @ahruss yes right. good call. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a `for` loop is safe. Semicolons will never be inserted in places where they would create empty statements.